# scatter_matrix in pandas returns lots of text - how to remove it?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

When I use scatter_matrix function from pandas, I get lots of text like

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001BD9F985860>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000001BD9F9C0588>,
```

Anyone knows how to tell pandas not to return this text?

Comment: have you tried ending the line of code with `;`?

Comment: otherwise assign the output to a variable, e.g. `axes = ...`

Comment: Thanks... Apologies of course ```;``` works... I must be tired. Thanks.

Comment: Learned a `;` can be used to suppress output in jupyter. Question and answers are legit. Please reopen.

Answer (score 10):

The [`scatter_matrix` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) returns the array of axes it generates, in case you want to modify them.

In an interactive Python console (IPython, the last line of an IPython notebook cell, etc.), return values (apart from `None`) are printed to the console (or the output of the cell, respectively), to it easier to see what is going on. If you were to run `scatter_matrix` as part of a script, this would not be printed, it would just be thrown away.

If you assign the return value to a variable

```
axes = scatter_matrix(...)
```

you get no output. The same applies *in IPython* (including notebooks, not in vanilla python with the `>>>` prompt) when you execute an empty statement after the the calculation – which is what adding `;` to the end of the line does

```
scatter_matrix(...);
```

there is no return value to be echoed, so there is not output.

Compare

```
In[1]: 5
Out[1]: 5

In[2]: x=5

In[3]: 5;

In[4]: 5; 6
Out[4]: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

[Thanks to @IanS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115244/scatter-matrix-in-pandas-returns-lots-of-text-how-to-remove-it/52115582#comment91181188_52115244). Of course, a `;` at the end of the line works.